# JQuery AJAX and XHR2 responseType "document"

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am requesting a website with JQuery's ajax function. I am a little bit unclear about the responseType of the XHR request. So far I am using the "dataType: "html"" attribute but I am not happy with it.

I'd rather have a complete HTMLDocument returned which would allow me traverse its DOM tree and scrape information as needed. I believe the "document" responseType is supported by XHR2 requests.

How can this be done with JQuery? Is there a way that it will return a DOMtree that I can navigate through?

Comment: jQuery is perfectly happy parsing xml, just wrap it up ;)
 $(responseXML)

Comment: This was my first impulse as well. But upon setting the dataType to "xml" I get an error:
  

Invalid XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>↵<!DOCTYPE html
  
I have not means of editing the document I am trying to scrape (I belongs to our local cafeteria). So there is no way to make it valid XML. That's why wanted to retrieve it as HTMLDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following to your `$.ajax()` call:

```
xhrFields: { responseType: "document" },
```

To retrieve the document object, your `success` call should look like this:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
  if (textStatus == "success") {
    myResponse = request.responseXML;
  }
  else
    // Not successful
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, even for this old question. I have learned a lot about JQuery since then... The JQuery API with Defereds is certainly the way to go.

Comment: I've just started jQuery (obviously, since I found this question Googling for my own purposes.) I'll look into using the Deferred object going forward. Thanks!